# Using boost::promise and boost::future in a loop

Tags: multithreading, boost

I want to start an undefined (at compile time) amount of threads and wait for their results together.

I want to use boost::thread (and boost::promise, ::shared_future).
I've the following code:

For simplicity this just returns a integer value.

```
class Test
{
public:
static void histograms(boost::promise<int>& p)
{
    p.set_value(16);
}
};
```

Here would be how I call use promise and future:

```
int main()
{
    // vector with final results
    std::vector<int> results;
    // vector with all futures from boost threads
    std::vector<boost::shared_future<int>> futures;
    // loop through all operations
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        // setup boost future and promise
        boost::promise<int> p;
       boost::shared_future<int> f = p.get_future();
        // add future to the vector to access it later
        futures.push_back(f);
        boost::thread t{ histograms, std::ref(p) };
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++)
    {
```

In this line I get a broken_promise exception:

```
        results.push_back(futures[i].get());

    }

    for (int i : results)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to print out 7 lines as i start 7 threads and should get 7 results in this example. But for the first time it gets to the line `futures[i].get` I immediately get a broken_promise exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour.

You create `promise` instance as local variable inside *for* scope. When the scope goes out, `p` is destroyed and you have dangling reference inside thread function - `histograms`.

Solution?
You can store `promise` in smart pointer (`shared_ptr`) to prolong its lifetime.

```
class Test
{
public:
    static void histograms(boost::shared_ptr< boost::promise<int> > p)
    {
        p->set_value(16);
    }
};
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::promise<int> >  p = boost::make_shared< boost::promise<int> >();
    boost::shared_future<int> f = p->get_future();
    futures.push_back(f);
    boost::thread t{ &Test::histograms, p }; // [1]
    t.detach(); // to be compatible with C++11
}
```

in [1] `p` is passed by value to increment reference-counter. So even if the *for* loop scope goes out, `promise` on which thread function - `histograms` works still exists.